# PyTorch weak_script_method decorator

Tags: python, pytorch

I came across some code in an introduction to Word2Vec and PyTorch that I'm not quite familiar with. I haven't seen this type of code structure before.

```
>>> import torch
>>> from torch import nn

>>> # an Embedding module containing 10 tensors of size 3
>>> embedding = nn.Embedding(10, 3)
>>> # a batch of 2 samples of 4 indices each
>>> input = torch.LongTensor([[1,2,4,5],[4,3,2,9]])
>>> embedding(input)

tensor([[[-0.0251, -1.6902,  0.7172],
         [-0.6431,  0.0748,  0.6969],
         [ 1.4970,  1.3448, -0.9685],
         [-0.3677, -2.7265, -0.1685]],

        [[ 1.4970,  1.3448, -0.9685],
         [ 0.4362, -0.4004,  0.9400],
         [-0.6431,  0.0748,  0.6969],
         [ 0.9124, -2.3616,  1.1151]]])
```

I'm a little confused about the following line of code.

```
>>> embedding(input)
```

I may have inadvertently ignored this syntax in the past, but I don't recall seeing a variable being passed to a class instance before? Referring to the PyTorch [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/sparse.html#Embedding) where `Class Embedding()` is defined, is this behaviour enabled with decorator `@weak_script_method` wrapping `def forward()`? The code below suggests this may be the case?

```
>>> torch.manual_seed(2)
>>> torch.eq(embedding(input), embedding.forward(input)).all()

tensor(1, dtype=torch.uint8)
```

Why is the use of decorator `@weak_script_method` preferable in this case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, `@weak_script_method` has nothing to do with it. `embedding(input)` follows the Python function call syntax, which can be used with both "traditional" functions and with objects which define the [`__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__call__) magic function. So this code

```
class Greeter:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.name = name

    def __call__(self, name):
        print('Hello to ' + name + ' from ' + self.name + '!')

greeter = Greeter('Jatentaki')
greeter('EBB')
```

will result in `Hello to EBB from Jatentaki!` being printed to stdout. Similarly, `Embedding` is an object which you construct by telling it how many embeddings it should contain, what should be their dimensionality, etc, and then, after it is constructed, you can call it like a function, to retrieve the desired part of the embedding.

The reason you do not see `__call__` in `nn.Embedding` source is that it subclasses `nn.Module`, which provides an automatic `__call__` implementation which delegates to `forward` and calls some extra stuff before and afterwards (see the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.forward)). So, calling `module_instance(arguments)` is roughly equivalent to calling `module_instance.forward(arguments)`.

The `@weak_script_method` decorator has little to do with it. It is related to [`jit`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/jit.html) compatibility, and `@weak_script_method` is a variant of `@script_method` designed for internal use in PyTorch - the only message for you should be that `nn.Embedding` is compatible with `jit`, if you wanted to use it.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback/documentation. Would you advise using `module_instance(arguments)` over `module_instance.forward(arguments)`? Is there a specific case where you would need to choose between the two variations, other than preference?

Comment: As given in the [documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.html#torch.nn.Module.forward) of `forward` "Although the recipe for forward pass needs to be defined within this function, one should call the `Module` instance afterwards instead of this since the former takes care of running the registered hooks while the latter silently ignores them.".